# SQL Find Related Bodies of Text

Tags: php, mysql, ios, sql, json

I'm having problems with finding similar text in a SQL column. I want to match up similar text in the BODY column from a user with other user's text in the BODY column.  The MYSQL error says the subquery returns multiple rows but I'm not sure why that would be an issue.  Please see the jSON link to see what I'm talking about.  Please let me know if you need any more information from me.

JSON: http://shipstudent.com/complaint_desk/centralwall.php

MySQL:

```
SELECT profile_picture, body, post_date, filename, username FROM Posts, Users WHERE Posts.IDUser = Users.IDUser AND Posts.body LIKE (SELECT Posts.body FROM Posts WHERE Posts.IDUser = (SELECT Users.IDUser FROM Users WHERE Users.username = "noah")) ORDER BY `Posts`.`post_date` DESC;
```

Comment: How do you define "*similar text*"?

Comment: i think `LIKE` does not provide fuzzy match but wildcard match

Comment: You have `WHERE username = (SELECT ...)` . If the subquery returns more than one row, then it's impossible to check for direct equality.  You may want to use `WHERE username = IN (SELECT ...)` instead.

Comment: Similar as in a wildcard match of text.  The username was replaced by IDUser and the = IN does not work, it has the same effect.